# Running c# code behind from a aspx page on load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page that I want to populate.  I have the query in my c#.  How would I run the query on page load from the aspx page?

```
function load()
{
    <%# Test_Message() %>
}
```

The code is not getting to the c#, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. Be as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong embedded code block syntax with `<%#`, instead use `<%=`, like this:

```
function load()
{
    <%= Test_Message() %>
}
```

Here is a description of the most common embedded code block syntaxes:

- `<%# %>` is for data-binding expressions
- `<%= %>` is the equivalent of `Response.Write()`
- `<% %>` runs server-side code, like an if-else block
- `<%: %>` is for HTML-encoding the data
- `<%@ %>` is for directives, usually page directives in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

That looks like JavaScript, to populate client side variable with server side value have such code:

```
function load()
{
    var message = "<%=Test_Message() %>";
    alert(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a text method, creat a text box object, then in the page load function of your c#, have

```
MY_TEXTBOX.Text = Test_Message()
```